# Android App to get the utilization of Access Point

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wifimanager

I am working on an android application and I want to make this app be able to tell me how many devices are connected to the current access point I am attached to. What is the best possible solution for this. I don't want the details of devices instead I just need the number of devices connected to a particular access point. I want to use this data for my web GUI which will show the utilization trend for each access point. Please suggest the way how to do this.

So far, I have written the application which tells me different information such as ESSID, BSSID, signal strength, delay etc. I want to add another field which tells me the number of devices connected to the access point I am connected with. My code so far is as shown below:this application sends all the information to a database in json format and from that database I want to show the trend of different performance and utilization parameters. Can someone help me achieving my goal of getting the list of connected devices.

```
package com.uhperk.mobilesensor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Formatter;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public double lon, lat, alt, acc;
    public Boolean isBetterLocation;
    public Long delay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // GPS
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.v("HELLO", "New location was found");
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
                alt = location.getAltitude();
                acc = location.getAccuracy();

                Log.v("Latitude", Double.toString(lat));
                Log.v("Longitude", Double.toString(lon));
                Log.v("Altitude", Double.toString(alt));
                Log.v("Accuracy", Double.toString(acc));

            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 0, locationListener);
        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Button buttonTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);
        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Implementing Accuracy on location information

            protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
                if (currentBestLocation == null) {
                    // A new location is always better than no location
                    return true;
                }
                // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
                long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
                boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > (1000 * 60 * 2);
                boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -(1000 * 60 * 2);
                boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

                // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
                // because the user has likely moved
                if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
                    return true;
                    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
                } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
                int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
                boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 2;
                boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 2;
                boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

                // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
                boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                        currentBestLocation.getProvider());

                // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
                if (isMoreAccurate) {
                    return true;
                } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
                    return true;
                } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
            private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
                if (provider1 == null) {
                    return provider2 == null;
                }
                return provider1.equals(provider2);
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // WIFI
                WifiManager mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();
                int level = wifiInfo.getRssi();
                String mac = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
                String essid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();

                int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
                String ipstr = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
                        (ipAddress & 0xff),
                        (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
                        (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),
                        (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));


                Log.v("Signal Level", Integer.toString(level));
                Log.v("MAC Address", mac);
                Log.v("ESSID", essid);
                Log.v("BSSID", bssid);
                Log.v("IP Address", ipstr);

                TextView essidLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.essidLab);
                TextView bssidLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bssidLab);
                TextView macLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.macLab);

                TextView IPLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IPLab);
                TextView signalLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signalLab);
                TextView latLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latLab);
                TextView lonLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lonLab);
                TextView altLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AltLab);
                TextView accLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccLab);

                essidLab.setText(essid);
                bssidLab.setText(bssid);
                macLab.setText(mac);
                IPLab.setText(ipstr);
                signalLab.setText(Integer.toString(level));
                latLabel.setText(Double.toString(lat));
                lonLabel.setText(Double.toString(lon));
                altLabel.setText(Double.toString(alt));
                accLabel.setText(Double.toString(acc));

                //Ping Trace

                //try {

                    //DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
                    //int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                    //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                    //int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                    //HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://172.xx.xx.xxx/bigfile");
                    //httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    //httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    //long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                    //InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    //byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    //while(inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {

                    //}
                    //long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //delay = end - start;

                //} catch(IOException e) {

                //}

                //Log.v("RTT", Long.toString(delay));
                //TextView delLab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Delaytime);
                //delLab.setText(Long.toString(delay));

                 //send data

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.accumulate("lat", lat);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("lon", lon);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("ss", level);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("mac", mac);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("essid", essid);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("bssid", bssid);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("ip", ipstr);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("alt", alt);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("acc", acc);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("res", delay);

                    // and so on ...

                    String json = jsonObject.toString();
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                    Log.d("JSON", json);

                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
                    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://172.xx.xx.xxx:81/push");
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
                    String result;
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("JSON", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                } catch (Exception e){
                    throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:"+ "http://172.xx.xx.xxx/bigfile", e);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post such long code snippets here. Especially since there seems to be nothing wrong with your code. If I understood your question correctly then it's even totally unrelated to your code in first place. AFAIK routers do not tell all clients how many clients they have in total. You'll have to look for a way to get that number out of your specific router. Ask its manufacturer maybe.